# Ant flaka: declare variable with dynamic name

Tags: ant, flaka

I'm using ant with flaka.

**How can I declare a variable with dynamic name (retrieved from another variable)?**

I would like to do something like that:

```
<fl:let>
    #{varname} = value
</fl:let>
```

however, i think it's illegal.

How can i do that?

*thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

second anwser :

your question is not clear to me :

```
#{variablename} = value
```

would overwrite an existing variable variablename, so my second guess is with "based on" you meant something like :

```
    <project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">          

      <fl:let>
        varname = 'foo'
        ; declare variable based on other variable
        #{varname}bar = 'whatever'
      </fl:let>

      <fl:echo>
        #{varname}
        #{foobar}
      </fl:echo>

    </project>
```

output :

```
  [fl:echo] foo
  [fl:echo] whatever
```

first answer :

Here's the FAQ entry from the official [Ant FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property) solved with [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

  <fl:install-property-handler />

  <property name="foo" value="foo.value" />
  <property name="var" value="foo" />
  <echo> #{${var}} = foo.value </echo>

</project>
```